# Adding two Merge Field gives Syntax Error in Formula (MS Word)

Tags: ms-word, formula, mergefield

I'm supposed to add two merge fields using formula and it's throwing syntax error
[image]

This is what i am trying to add
[image]

I've tried the bookmark thing
I've tried using ctrl+f9 for brackets
I've tried inserting merge fields using menu and manually using ctrl f9
I've tried integer merge fields and decimal merge fields
In short, i have read so many blogs and tried all the possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

That is to be expected, because Word is trying the evaluate the mergefields, not their results. Previewing the merge or executing it should generate the correct result. If there is the possibility that either field will be empty, you can either:

- Add numeric picture switches to the mergefield field codes; or
- Prefix the mergefields with 0.

Hence, either:

- {={MERGEFIELD SIF_Out \# 0.00}-{MERGEFIELD SIF_In \# 0.00}}; or
- {=0«SIF_Out»-0«SIF_In»}

Note that the '\# 0.00' numeric switch allows for up to two decimals. For other numeric formatting options see: *Mailmerge Number & Currency Formatting* in **Mailmerge Tips & Tricks** page at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Still throwing the syntax error right after when it gets the mergefield's first tag. i.e to be «

Comment: That suggests you're typing the «. You can't do that, the mergefields need to be inserted via the Insert Merge Field dialogue.

Comment: i am adding the merge field using the dialog

Comment: i added the formula and then inserted mergefields in it and used the both suggestions you gave . i.e. prefix before the mergefields and numeric switches.

Comment: @SabaAli FWIW my diagnosis would also be that Word is picking up an actual « character. Because normally you never see them within an { = } field if you inserted the fields correctly. But 1. What if you insert the Sif_Out mergefield from the menu, then type the - sign after it, then insert the Sif_in mergefield from the menu. Then select all that, click ctrl-F9 to insert a pair of { } field codes, and put an = sign after the { ?

Comment: Are you getting that result when you preview or execute the merge? If not, then as I said in my answer, the error is most likely because "*Word is trying the evaluate the mergefields, not their results. Previewing the merge or executing it should generate the correct result.*"

Comment: Nope, Still getting the syntax error @jonsson

Comment: Whenever i update the formula, it gives me the syntax error « here @macropod

Comment: @SabaAli as a workaround you could try the following set of field codes: { SET SIFOut { MERGEFIELD SIF_Out } }{ SET SIFIn { MERGEFIELD SIF_In } }{ =SIFOut-SIFIn } . Another thing you could try to have a look at the problem is to make a copy of your Document, cut out everything except the {=} field with the nested MERGEFIELD fields, then save the document as Microsoft Word XML format. Then open the .xml file ina text editor such as Notepad, find the text <w:body , find the first <w:p after that, copy everything from there to the following </w:p, and edit your question to include that text.

Comment: @SabaAli Nothing you have posted so far indicates clearly that you are actually previewing or executing the merge. In preview mode, mergefields show their results, not the fields - and it's the results that Word evaluates. I have used such field constructions many times and have never encountered Word generating syntax errors because of them in either mailmerge previews or mailmerge executions.